# Showing widget before SOAP connection

Tags: python, soap, kivy

Problem is in LoginForm.log_in() (code below)

I would like in that order:

1. clear widgets
2. show MenuWindow widget
3. connect via SOAP.

Unfortunately I can't. I don't know why but my app first tries to connect to SOAP server and then cleans widget tree and creates new.

main.py:

```
# coding=utf-8
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from suds.client import Client
import sys
import os
import time, threading


class LoginForm(BoxLayout):
    login_input = ObjectProperty()
    password_input = ObjectProperty()

    def log_in(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        menu = Factory.MenuWindow()
        self.add_widget(menu)
        MenuWindow.change_caption(MenuWindow)

    def show_settings(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        pokaz = Factory.SettingsWindow()
        self.add_widget(pokaz)


def set_written_data_ip():
    store = JsonStore('anakonda_mobile.json')
    if store.exists('Adres'):
        print(store.get('Adres'))
        if store.get('Adres')['ip'].strip() != '':
            return store.get('Adres')['ip']
    else:
        return ''


def set_written_data_port():
    store = JsonStore('anakonda_mobile.json')
    if store.exists('Adres'):
        if store.get('Adres')['port'].strip() != '':
            return store.get('Adres')['port']
    else:
        return ''


class SettingsWindow(BoxLayout):
    ip_value = ObjectProperty(set_written_data_ip())
    port_value = ObjectProperty(set_written_data_port())

    def show_logging(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(LoginForm())

    def save_ip_port(self):
        store = JsonStore('anakonda_mobile.json')
        store.put('Adres', ip=self.ip_input.text, port=self.port_input.text)
        python = sys.executable
        os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)


class MenuWindow(BoxLayout):
    def soap_connect(self):
        try:
            self.a = Client('http://192.168.1.1:7789/ASOAPService?wsdl')
        except Exception as g:
        return ''

    def change_caption(self):
        self.soap_connect(self)
        return 'SOAP connected'


class MobileApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MobileApp().run()
```

mobile.kv

```
LoginForm:
<LoginForm>:
    login_input: _login
    password_input: _password
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        Label:
            text: 'Login: '
        TextInput:
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            id: _login
        Label:
            text: 'Hasło: '
        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            id: _password
            password: True
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            text:'Zaloguj'
            on_press: root.log_in()
        Button:
            text: 'Ustawienia'
            on_press: root.show_settings()
    BoxLayout:


<SettingsWindow>:
    ip_input: _ip
    port_input: _port
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        Label:
            text: 'IP: '
        TextInput:
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            id: _ip
            text: root.ip_value
        Label:
            text: 'Port: '
        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            id: _port
            text: root.port_value
    Button:
        text: 'Cofnij'
        on_press: root.show_logging()
    Button:
        text: 'Zapisz'
        on_press: root.save_ip_port()

<MenuWindow>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        Label:
            id: _napis
            text: 'polaczenie'
            #text: root.change_caption()
        Button:
            text: 'Cofnij'
```